# Send simultaneous requests with async/await syntax and don't lost all results in case of one request failure

Tags: javascript, async-await, ecmascript-2017

Two or more requests are sent simultaneously inside `Promise.all`. Then their responses are handled appropriately. But in case one of them is failed the rest of results is lost.

```
async init function ()
   const [userInfo, balance] = 
      await Promise.all([
          Promise.reject('get user info error'), // getUserInfo(), 
          Promise.resolve(5000) // getBalance()
      ])
   this.userInfo = userInfo
   this.balance = balance // it won't be initialized
}
```

Can that be handled without rewriting above code to old promise .. then().catch() style?

Comment: async/await and try...catch are just syntactic sugar for .then and .catch. No, this can't be handled with single async function and without .catch.

Comment: @estus We could always replace `x.catch(h)` with `(async function() { try { return await x; } catch(e) { return h(e); }}())`, but we can't reasonably call this "syntactic sugar" any more :-)